# How do i include "sample code" in my article content

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am building a coding tutorial website using the Drupal platform. I want to display my sample code in a fixed non-line break block.

Comment: To display it where?

Answer (score 1):

There is [CKEditor CodeSnippet](https://www.drupal.org/project/codesnippet), which has an integration module.

Comment: RIght EnemyStar this is the best Drupal8 contributed module to use code snippet.